# AngularJS: X-Auth-Token not sent (error 401)

Tags: angularjs, spring, cors

I'm here because I tried everything and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

As a backend, I use Spring MVC, Rest and Spring Security. I'm using a custom authentication's system based on tokens (entirely stateless). I've also a CORS's filter, because my front app is not running on the same server.

So here's what I did in angularJS, in order to get authenticate when I want to access a protected resource:

- I've created an interceptor that change each request to add the token found from a cookie
- I add a custom header on the request

Here's what my interceptor do:

```
request: function(config) {
            var token = $cookieStore.get("token");
            if (token && token.key) {

                config.headers["X-Auth-Token"]=token.key;

            }
            console.log(config.headers);

            return  config || $q.when(config);
        }
```

But when I try to access a protected resource, even if the token is still valid, it never puts the X-Auth-Token headers on the request! It tried to send an option's request and failed with a 401 error!

But if I do the same with a url parameter (like token=....), the interceptor works as expected...(I've implemented both system : by parameter and by header)

What I don't understand is why the header is not put as expected?? and why it works perfectly with something like POSTMAN for instance?

Please help, I'm losing my hairs with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably cleaner to do this instead of your accepted answer.

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: hi there, i had exactly the same problem and the solution does work. however i do not fully understand why. could somebody pls explain this.
why is the handling different for options and why is the filter chain skipped?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing my filter like this:

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        LOG.info("goes on the filter");

```
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET,  DELETE, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Auth-Token");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        try {
            response.getWriter().print("OK");
            response.getWriter().flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but $cookieStore can only get/set strings, so the following:

```
var token = $cookieStore.get("token");
        if (token && token.key) {
```

Will never evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks, I do this because the cookie could be not found. Even without the condition the problem persist. The weird thing is if I do a console.log of config.headers, the x auth token is present. But when the request is executed, it failed directly and the token is not present.Not sure if the problem is on angular or in my backend .